# setState is not working in react native for boolen

Tags: react-native, setstate

Here is my code, I want to change the boolen value of isCourse but is not changing. It's showing false in debugging. I also checked the if value is showing true

```
 const [appTheme, setAppTheme] = useState(Appearance.getColorScheme());
 const [isCourse, setIsCourse] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
   const handleDynamicLinks = dynamicLinks()
     .getInitialLink()
     .then(link => {
       console.log('here is your link', link.url);
       if (link && link.url === 'https://englishmuni.page.link/course') {
         setIsCourse(true);
         // console.log('--*****--', isCourse, link.url);
       }
     });

   const unsubscribe = dynamicLinks().onLink(handleDynamicLinks);
   Appearance.addChangeListener(scheme => {
     setAppTheme(scheme.colorScheme);
   });
   return () => unsubscribe();
 }, [isCourse]);
```

Comment: and yes, it should show `false`, read more about react component state https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory, and use state https://react.dev/reference/react/useState, to understand how to control component state correctly, and how state is being updated, TL;DR: you are printing the value in the same execution context of "triggering" updating the state, so the state is not updated yet, it is updated asynchronously, that will cause a component re-rendering with the new state values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be careful about the logic inside the `useEffect` to avoid infinite loops or any unintended side effects with `isCourse` since you're setting its value inside of it (`setIsCourse`).

You can call two `useEffect`s in which the first one without dependency array to initialize `isCourse` and the second `useEffect` to watch the changes to `isCourse`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  //You can create an async function here and put the logic inside
  const handleDynamicLinks = async () => {
    try {
      const link = await dynamicLinks().getInitialLink();
      console.log('here is your link', link.url);
      if (link && link.url === 'https://englishmuni.page.link/course') {
        setIsCourse(true);
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
      //TODO when exception occurs
    }
  };

  //Call the function
  handleDynamicLinks();

  const unsubscribe = dynamicLinks().onLink(handleDynamicLinks);
  const themeListener = Appearance.addChangeListener(scheme => {
    setAppTheme(scheme.colorScheme);
  });

  return () => {
    unsubscribe();
    themeListener.remove();  // Assuming the listener has a remove() method. If not, adjust accordingly.
  };
}, []); //<-- As stated before, we setup the useEffect with no dependency when the component is mounted for the first time.
```

Now coming on to the second `useEffect` where we actually observe the changes to `isCourse`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (isCourse) {
    //Work with the logic here.
  }
}, [isCourse]); //<-- And here, we observe the changes to isCourse
```

By splitting the logic into two separate `useEffect` hooks, you separate the logic for setting `isCourse` and the logic for responding to changes in its value. This can help avoid potential pitfalls like infinite loops.